# Adding http headers in Angular 6

Tags: angular, http, visual-studio-code, http-headers

Can anyone tell me if this is the correct way to add headers to http requests in Angular 6?

When I make the call via SwaggerUI, I can see the headers should be:

```
url -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'zumo-api-version: 2.0.0' 'https://myurl/tables/stuff'
```

so I have added the following:

```
let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.append('HttpHeader1', 'Accept:application/json');
headers = headers.append('HttpHeader2', 'zumo-api-version:2.0.0');
```

And then the call:

```
getStuff(){
    return this.http.get('https://myurl/tables/stuff', {headers})
  }
```

There is no failure but nothing is returned, and I know that there should be.

thanks

UPDATE

Have just noticed that the url in my call is actually https not http, would that make any difference?

```
getStuff(){
        return this.https.get('https://myurl/tables/stuff', {headers})
      }
```

Comment: Where you've got `HttpHeader1` should actually be the header name, i.e. `Accept`, and where you've got `Accept:application/json` should be the value, i.e. `application/json`, so what you actually want is `headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');`

Comment: Make sure you call `subscribe` on your HTTP call as well. Observables are lazy, so it will only make the HTTP call once something has subscribed

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The correct way to set **[`headers`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders)** is

```
let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
headers = headers.append('zumo-api-version', '2.0.0');
```

Comment: thanks, then the call should still be:  getStuff(){
    return this.http.get('https://myurl/tables/stuff', {headers})
  } ?

Comment: sir i tried ur code but i got ERROR TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object in the console can u tell me how to fix?

Answer (score 10):

Angular 6 format:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'zumo-api-version': '2.0.0'
});
```

Comment: try to change 'Accept': 'application/json' to  'Content-Type': 'application/json'

Comment: short and simple method to set headers :)

Answer (score 3):

The correct format to set the **headers** would be as shown below.

```
let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
headers = headers.append('zumo-api-version', '2.0.0');
```

`url -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'zumo-api-version: 2.0.0' 'https://myurl/tables/stuff'`

In the above request the name of the header keys is **Accept** & **zumo-api-version** , the text preceding the **:**
Headers are basically set as key/value pairs

Comment: let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this._http
  .get(this._url,options)

make sure you make the call to get request using above statement, by passing the headers in request call

Comment: same thing - no data, and yes I get it returned in swagger.  Think I'm missing the subscribe though, I'll test that in the morning, home time now.

Comment: If it's a GET request, there will be no content, so Content-Type won't matter

Answer (score 1):

In angular 6+

*declaration zone:*

```
httpOptionsNoAuth : any;
```

*initialization:*

```
constructor(){
    this.httpOptionsNoAuth = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('No-Auth', 'true')
    };
}
```

*usage:*

```
return this._http.get<any>(`${url}`, { headers: this.httpOptionsNoAuth.headers});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting nothing in return because you're not subscribing to that event. add `.subcribe` to that function where ever you're calling it **eg**

`getStuff().subscribe(data=>{
console.log(data);
}
)`

so the `data` you're subscribing to contains all the response and everything you need to know about that call.

You can read more from here https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 0):

I have done it like this in my code

```
httpOptions={ headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})};
 this.httpOptions.headers = this.httpOptions.headers.append('Token', this.Token);
```

And then in my http.get call, I have done this:

```
return this.http.get<JSON>(this.API_ADDRESS+'/api/RemoveEmployee/'+id,this.httpOptions
```

Answer (score -3):

Try below code that might help you.

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Accept': 'application/json').set('zumo-api-version': '2.0.0')
```

Comment: At least learn to format your OWN codes before trying to help others.

Comment: @JhourladEstrella thank you for advice. I will take care of next time.

Comment: Downvoted, because the syntax for adding a header is inaccurate.  The correct method is `append`, not `set`.

Comment: I give this for Angular 6. [https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders]