# Angular - authentication headers

Tags: angular, authentication, http-headers

I have an Java backend that provides me some API's that are protected with authentication.

So if I call it using any browser or postman with Authorization I have an `200 (Ok)` response, but If I set `httpHeaders` with the same user and password, I get `401 (Unauthorized)`.

**The call:**

```js
let username: string = 'admin';
let password: string = 'pe';
let headers =  new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization' , 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password)).set('Content-Type', 'application/json').set('cache-control', 'no-cache'); 
console.log(headers);

let params = new HttpParams().set('instID', value).set('procType', 'M');
    
return this.httpClient.get<pe_process_instance[]>('http://' + this.urlConfig.BASE_URL + ':' + this.urlConfig.PORT + '/' + this.urlConfig.WSBaseURL + '/getipeprocessinstances', { headers: headers , params: params });
```

**The response:**

[image: response image]

What I am missing here? Do I correctly set my headers?

Comment: i think best practice is  use `interceptor`

Comment: follow this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51989482/adding-http-headers-in-angular-6

Comment: @Abhishek don't see how the answer will help me :/

Comment: Well, this seems to fail on the options request, seems to me that this is a CORS issue. Have you correctly setup CORS in backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set your `headers` in this way:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();

headers = headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password));
headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers = headers.append('cache-control', 'no-cache');
```

When you use `.set()` multiple times you overwrite your headers each time, and only last header is send.

Comment: I think that I have another idea why you have a problem with this request. Look, that `401` you get for `Option` request, not for  `GET` and this is a difference between your `browser` version and `REST client` request, where you don't have `CORS` issue. I think that your problem is not a Angular App but Java server.
In normal way you should get `200` from `OPTION` and eventually `401` from `GET`. I think that you should disable `OPTION` request from your Authentication process.

Comment: you mean disable OPTION in the back-end?

Comment: Not disable `OPTION`, but disable authentication for `OPTION` request. I had similar problem few years ago with `PHP Symfony` framework, and I found solution where `OPTION` request get round authentication process.
This is very important because OPTION request doesn't have custom headers, so authentication can't pass for them.

Comment: Did you found solution?