# Angular Headers was set in request header

Tags: java, angular

I have a an angular project, In my service class i am setting the headers in the request but it was set the value in in header, How do i resolve it?

Here i have tried for server side and angular side both.

```
return this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl+'addkeystore',params,{ headers: new HttpHeaders({'tenantID': "123"}) });
```

And at my server side

```
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");
```

Comment: please make your question clearer , if you want to pass header and params first define the header `let headers = new HttpHeaders({'tenantID': "123"});` then set pass both header and params inside one object    `return this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl+'addkeystore',{ params,headers });`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding http headers in Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51989482/adding-http-headers-in-angular-6)