# Angular 8 error: Http failure during parsing for http

Tags: angular, rxjs

I get an error when trying to call a service from Angular 8 app.
Here is the service:

```
const httpOptionsPlain = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Accept': 'text/plain',
                             'Content-Type': 'text/plain'                             
                             })
};

@Injectable()
export class TripService {

public getTripNameById(tripId: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.baseUrl}/Trips/Trip/Name/${tripId}`,  httpOptionsPlain);
  }
```

And here is the Java rest api (works fine when calling from the browser):

```
@GET
@Path("Trip/Name/{fundId}")
@Produces("text/plain")     
public String getTripNameById(@PathParam("tripId") Integer tripId) {        
    return myDao.getNameById(tripId);       
}
```

I'm getting the error in the chrome console:

> error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse () at XMLHtt…, text: "AAA BBB CCC"}
>       headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
>       message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/...
>       name: "HttpErrorResponse"

I'm sending plain text so I'm not why the service try to parse json.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51989482/adding-http-headers-in-angular-6/52100181

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please try

```
const httpOptionsPlain = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Accept': 'text/plain',
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  }),
  'responseType': 'text'
};

@Injectable()
export class TripService {

public getTripNameById(tripId: number): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.get<string>(`${this.baseUrl}/Trips/Trip/Name/${tripId}`,  httpOptionsPlain);
  }
```

I've just added `'` to the responseType

Comment: can you fixed the header, i'm getting error "not json format"

Comment: @user2304483 maybe you are looking for somothing like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56865204/getting-typescript-error-for-options-configuration-in-an-angular-8-app/56865357#56865357) ?

Answer (score 5):

HttpClient by default converts response to be response.json(). In case you are API returns non-json response, you have to specify that

```
this.http.get(url, {responseType: 'text'}).
```

In your code make it non-generic by removing `<string>` return type for it to work -

```
return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/Trips/Trip/Name/${tripId}`,  httpOptionsPlain);
```

Comment: I can confirm that this approach works well to resolve this issue.