# Getting typescript error for options configuration in an Angular 8 app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm getting the following error when trying to call a service using rest api
and a get call:

> Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; responseType: string; }'
>   is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | {
>   [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?:
>   HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?:
>   boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.
>         Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible.
>           Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"json"'.ts(2345)

```
 const httpOptionsText = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Accept': 'text/plain',
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  }),
  responseType: 'text'
};
```

Here is the service call with httpOptionsPlain as parameter which is error is
signed.

```
@Injectable()
export class TripService {

public getTripNameById(tripId: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.baseUrl}/Trips/Trip/Name/${tripId}`,  httpOptionsText);
  }
```

The error is on the editor only (the code works fine). Thanks.

Comment: Which editor are you using? VS Code?

Comment: Yes, I'm using visual code

Comment: Can you try to use `responseType: 'text' as 'json'` in your headers?

Comment: That's fixed the error, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your code to

```
  public getTripNameById(tripId: number): Observable<any> {
    const httpOptionsText = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        Accept: "text/plain",
        "Content-Type": "text/plain"
      }),
      responseType: "text" as "json"
    };
    return this.http.get<any>(
      `${this.baseUrl}/Trips/Trip/Name/${tripId}`,
      httpOptionsText
    );
  }
```