# {Angular} Error trying to connect to server (Http failure during parsing for)

Tags: json, angular, http, server, json-server

I'm trying to make a dynamic web page. I have the data in a local json and I want to connect to a mock server using json-server.

If I use a local address (like "src/assets/data/data.json") there are no errors and I can access without complications. The problem comes when I want to do the same using the address "http://localhost:5000".

`ERROR Object { headers: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:5000/", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:5000/", error: {…} }`

I searched for information but didn't find (or didn't understand) how to fix it. I don't know if it will help (and I found it on the Internet) but if I add "|json" to the interpolation code I get "null" as a result. Well, I leave my code. Any help is appreciated.

An example json:

```
{
  "block":{
    "block1":"block1",
    "block2":"block2",
    "block3":"block3"
  }
}
```

My service:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyserviceService {
  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/'
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getData():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
  }
}
```

My component template "connection":

```
<h1 style="text-align: center;">{{myTest?.block.block1}}</h1>
<h1 style="text-align: center;">{{myTest?.block.block2}}</h1>
<h1 style="text-align: center;">{{myTest?.block.block3}}</h1>
```

My component ts:

```
import { MyserviceService } from './../../services/myservice.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-connection',
  templateUrl: './connection.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./connection.component.css']
})
export class ConnectionComponent implements OnInit {
  myTest:any;
  constructor(private dataTest:MyserviceService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataTest.getData().subscribe(data => {
      this.myTest = data;
    });
  }
}
```

I have also recreated it in Stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tc-fd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fmyservice.service.ts

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408537/angular-httpclient-http-failure-during-parsing or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56864107/angular-8-error-http-failure-during-parsing-for-http

Comment: What do you serve with json-server? Can you show what you get when you run the json-server and browse to http://localhost:5000 ?

Comment: Regarding the duplicate thing, I have read them but I have not understood them nor am I sure if they really tell the way to solve my problem.

Regarding the second... Well, this is a bit embarrassing, I just solved it thanks to your question. Indeed, the first thing it displayed was the welcome page, and further down, I had the resources leading to the json. Simply by changing the service address to "localhost:5000/block" and making a small change in the template, it showed it. 

Thank you, and... I'll have to think a little better before asking again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit embarrassing, and I don't know if it's "correct", but I'll answer myself since I was able to solve it thanks to a simple question I was asked.

json-server has a welcome page, which in my case would be at the address "localhost:5000". The problem was that my program wanted to get information from the welcome page which is not json. But if I add the resource, which is in "localhost:5000/block", it does show it and my code would look like this.

```
export class MyserviceService {
  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/block'
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getData():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
  }
}
```

Plus a small change in the template.

```
<h1 style="text-align: center;">{{myTest?.block1}}</h1>
<h1 style="text-align: center;">{{myTest?.block2}}</h1>
<h1 style="text-align: center;">{{myTest?.block3}}</h1>
```

And that's it.

Although it was not what I expected, at least I solved it and learned.